# mybatis foreach to insert a list, how can i control transaction, it is autocommit now

Tags: foreach, transactions, mybatis

#i hope it can return some log, then continue insert

````
select * 
from seerid.buddyIds
where id REGEXP
<foreach collection="idSplits" item="item" index="index" open="'" close="'" separator="|">
    #{item}
</foreach>
</select>```
````

Comment: Are you trying to `INSERT` or to `SELECT`? Can you provide an example of how the SQL statement should look like if the list has three elements? With that, a `<foreach>` should be trivial to use.

Comment: Transactions are controlled at the programming level. If you are using Java/Spring, you just need to annotate the method where the call is with `@Transactional`.

Comment: What's database are you using?